# Async calls - how to wait for them on UI thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a landing page on a web site I am working on, and on the action for the page is called, a few async web calls are made in order to cache the results for later on. What I want to do, though, is wait for the calls to complete before moving to the next action. Basically I have:

```
GetParticipantInfo(planID, partID );

SetCurrentInvestments(partID, planID);

GetLoanFunds(planID, partID);
```

and each of those is split like this:

```
public void GetParticipantInfo(string planNumber, string participantID)
    {
        IAsyncResult _IAsyncResult;
        List<string> parameter = new List<string>();
        parameter.Add(planNumber);
        parameter.Add(participantID);
        GetParticipantInfo_A _GetParticipantInfo_A = new GetParticipantInfo_A(GetParticipantInfoAsync);
        _IAsyncResult = _GetParticipantInfo_A.BeginInvoke(participantID, planNumber, serviceContext, GetParticipantInfoAsyncCallBack, parameter);

    }

    public ParticipantDataModel GetParticipantInfoAsync(string planNumber, string partId, ServiceContext esfSC)
    {

        ParticipantDataModel pdm = new ParticipantDataModel();
        return pdm;

    }

    private void GetParticipantInfoAsyncCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            AsyncResult result;              
            result = (AsyncResult)ar;
            string planID = ((List<string>)ar.AsyncState)[0];
            GetParticipantInfo_A caller = (GetParticipantInfo_A)result.AsyncDelegate;
            ParticipantDataModel pdm = caller.EndInvoke(ar);
            _cacheManager.SetCache(planID, CacheKeyName.GetPartInfo.ToString(), pdm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

So the question is, how to I set up the UI thread to wait on the calls to finish before moving on to something else?

In response to Joe:

Ok, so assuming they all return the asyncresult, could I do something like:

```
List<IAsyncResult> results;
//After each call
result = OneOfTheAsyncCalls();
results.Add(result);

foreach(IAsyncResult result in results)
{
     result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

Or is the order going to matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle` to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete.

Your sample code (e.g. GetParticipantInfo) discards the `IAsyncResult`.  Instead, return it to the caller.

> See my edit to the original question

Yes your edit looks like it will work (or you can use `WaitAll` rather than looping on `WaitOne`).

Comment: I looked into that, but wasn't exactly sure how to implement it. Since the only place I really have access to the result is within the async "branch", I didn't know what to do with it. Evidently when you don't use the APM, the callback for an async method is also run on the worker thread, so I don't know where I'd use this.. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Would you be able to use AutoResetEvent between the caller and the async callback?

Comment: You tell me :P I'm fairly new to .NET, so I don't have a huge amount of knowledge here

Comment: AutoResetEvent is straightforward to use... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx - It allows you to wait in one calling function for the response in another async call back! Call WaitOne in the calling function with an optional timeout and call set after the response is received and processed! This will allow the calling function to then proceed from where it was waiting..

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your methods so that they use the `Task.FromAsync` method. For example, the `GetParticipantInfo` would look like this. I basically consolidated everything into this one method.

```
public Task<ParticipantDataModel> GetParticipantInfo(string planNumber, string participantID)
{
  var instance = new GetParticipantInfo_A(
    (planNumber, partID, esfSC) =>
    {
      return new ParticipantDataModel();
    }
  );
  var main = Task<ParticipantDataModel>.Factory.FromAsync(
    instance.BeginInvoke, 
    instance.EndInvoke, 
    participantID, 
    planNumber, 
    serviceContext,
    null);
  var continuation = main.ContinueWith(
    task =>
    {
      lock (_cacheManager)
      {
        _cacheManager.SetCache(planNumber, CacheKeyName.GetPartInfo.ToString(), task.Result);
      }
    });
  return continuation;
}
```

Then your page request code would look like the following. I used `Task.WaitAll` to block the page request thread until each individual task completes.

```
private void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var t1 = GetParticipantInfo(partID, plantID);
  var t2 = SetCurrentInvestments(partID, planID);
  var t3 = GetLoanFunds(planID, partID);
  Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, +1 for sure -- I wish I could accept multiple answers, but in this special case blocking the UI thread is actually what I want. I don't want to render the page until these calls are complete. The only reason they're async is so they'll call in parallel and take up a third of the time.

Comment: In a web app, you need to block the "UI thread" (i.e. the thread that is processing the request). This implementation (using "ContinueWith") will execute the three tasks sequentially - surely the OP wants them to execute in parallel?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: I misunderstood your question. I thought you were using a Winform or WPF application. I updated my answer to simplify it  quite a bit.

Comment: @Joe: Hmm...I bet you're right. I changed my answer accordingly.